# How to set where SpreadsheetApp saves spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to save a spreadsheet to a specific folder on Drive using google app script. However, I cannot see a method that allows me to do so.

using:
SpreadsheetApp.create(name)

saves it directly to Drive, is there a way to save it in a folder?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about these solutions? You can choose one of them freely.

`SpreadsheetApp.create()` cannot directly create in a special folder. It is created to the root folder. When you want to create new spreadsheet in a special folder, you can achieve using DriveApp and Drive API. The sample scripts are as follows.

### 1. Use DriveApp

When you use this, you can use by only copy and paste this to your script editor.

```
var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.create(name).getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
DriveApp.getFolderById("### folder ID ###").addFile(file);
file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
```

#### Flow :

1. Create new spreadsheet to root folder.
2. Add a special folder to the parents of created spreadsheet.
3. Remove the root folder from the parents of created spreadsheet.

---

### 2. Use Drive API

This can create directly new spreadsheet to the special folder. When you use this, you can use by copy and paste this to your script editor. **And then, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services and API console.**

```
Drive.Files.insert({
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
  "parents": [{"id": "### folder ID ###"}],
  "title": name
});
```

#### Enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Drive API v2

#### Enable Drive API at API console

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "Drive API". And click Google Drive API.
  - Click Enable button.

---

### References :

- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)
- [addFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#addFile(File))
- [removeFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removeFile(File))
- Advanced Google Services : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- Drive API v2: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Updated at August 28, 2020:

By [updating at July 27, 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#july_27_2020), `addFile(File)`, `addFolder(Folder)`, `removeFile(File)` and `removeFolder(Folder)` have been deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#expandable-1) From July 27, 2020, `file.moveTo(destination)` and `folder.moveTo(destination)` are used.

By this, above sample script can be changed as follows.

#### From:

```
var folderId = "###";
var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.create("sample name").getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile(file);
file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
```

#### To:

```
var folderId = "###";
var fileId = SpreadsheetApp.create("sample name").getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
file.moveTo(folder);
```

#### References:

- [file.moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)
- [folder.moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#moveTo(Folder))

Comment: I used option 2 and it worked a treat. Thanks for your help

Comment: @alexander cowie Thank you.

Comment: @alexander cowie :)